# Raspberry PI uhubctl permissions

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi4

Trying to use [uhubctl](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) to control power to USB ports. I want to write a bash script to automate the task.

Right now I can use sudo commands to get it to turn off and on.

```
sudo ./uhubctl -l 1-1 -a 0 
sudo ./uhubctl -l 1-1 -a 1
```

However I want to run these without sudo. I have added the permssions to the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/52-usb.rules`
Added the line `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{2109:3431}=="2001", MODE="0666"` 2109:3431 is for Raspberry pi 4B.
And then run `sudo udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=usb` and rebooted.

I keep getting the follwing errors

```
No compatible smart hubs detected!
Run with -h to get usage info.
There were permission problems while accessing USB.
To fix this, run this tool as root using 'sudo uhubctl',
or add one or more udev rules like below
to file '/etc/udev/rules.d/52-usb.rules':
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2001", MODE="0666"
then run 'sudo udevadm trigger --attr-match=subsystem=usb'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Leave `idVendor` alone, replace 2001 with 2109. Also, you will have to add 2nd line for USB 3 hub to make it work. You can find vid for all necessary hubs by running sudo uhubctl once

Comment: @mvp I tried your fix. I am still having to run it with sudo perms. However I don't understand what you mean about the 2nd line. According to the GitHub page they are all just linked together and shouldn't require a 2nd line. I am just using the onboard PI 4+ usb ports

Comment: USB 3 hubs will advertise themselves as 2 independent devices: USB 2 and USB 3. Often, they will have the same vendor id (e.g. 2109) - then one line is enough. But sometimes they advertise as 2 different vendor IDs, in this case you need to have both added (I am uhubctl author)